# Google sign-in button doesn't load in Firefox if parent element is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-openid

I'm using Google Sign-In JavaScript client to dynamically create a G+ Login button.
The code looks something like this:

```
<div id="googleSignInButton">
    <span class="g-signin"
        data-scope="openid email"
        data-clientid="{{flow.client_id}}"
        data-redirecturi="{{flow.redirect_uri}}"
        data-accesstype="offline"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-callback="googleLoginCallback"
        data-approvalprompt="force">
    </span>
</div>
```

It works fine. But in one specific situation it doesn't load.
When using firefox AND with it's parent element hidden (display:none), it doesn't show up at all when it's parent is shown.

Check jsfiddle for example (check the html comment):

https://jsfiddle.net/uh6cjt7a/3/

Comment: It's assigned a width and height of 1px when it's initially hidden.

Comment: I tried setting the width/height, but in the end it made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running on Firefox, if the element is "invisible" when you load the google API, it will set the width and height properties to 1px directly in the element's style. It's impossible to change it via CSS.

One solution is to explicitly initialize the API after you make the element visible. You can do it using the `go` method.

```
<script >
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'en-US',
    parsetags: 'explicit' //Configure to initialize explicitly
  };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

And them, in the javascript do this

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function showHide() {

  var login_panel = $("#login_panel");
  console.log(login_panel);
  var display = login_panel.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
  login_panel.style.display = display;
  gapi.signin.go(login_panel); //Initialize the API after the element becomes visible.
}
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uh6cjt7a/11/)
 with a working example.